# Getting error Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval'' in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I am trying to use Visual studio to make a universal windows app.  When I try to run the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>testProject</title>
    <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>Content goes here!</div><script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <form name="myForm">

           <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="yes"/>  Yes <br />
           <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="No"/> No <br />
           <input type="button" name="submit"value="submit" onsubmit="return validateForm" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In JavaScript main file:

```
function ValiditeForm(){

    document.writeln("Hello World");
}
```

When I attempt to run I get the following warning:

CSP14312: Resource violated directive 'script-src ms-appx: 'unsafe-eval'' in Host Defined Policy: inline script. Resource will be blocked.

All I am simply trying to do is write HTML code using the visual studio universal app that upon a user clicking a radio button in a HTML form, that it will be passed to a function in JavaScript and will print out a value.

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because of Content Security Policy

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy):

> The HTTP Content-Security-Policy response header allows web site administrators to control resources the user agent is allowed to load for a given page. With a few exceptions, policies mostly involve specifying server origins and script endpoints. This helps guard against cross-site scripting attacks (XSS).

Your server is sending a `Content-Security-Policy` HTTP header that is **preventing** your browser from trusting your javascript file.

You can change the CSP header so you can inline the `<script>`, if your server is IIS, look for the `HTTP Response heathers` option on `inetmgr.exe`

[image: inetmgr]

by deleting `unsafe-eval` from your configuration you're all set.

[image: unsafe-eval]

And this is OK for development, but not for production environments. There are some cool utilities on the internet that could help you generate a valid CSP for specific files. Google for "CSP header generator" for instance.

Answer (score -1):

Correct all other syntax errors.  Click off the error message you get while the program is running (the 'x' at the top of the error output window).  Terminate your program.  Close your solution.  Exit Visual Studio.

RENAME your project folder.  Open Visual Studio from the new folder.  REBUILD your solution.  Now when
you debug, you will not see the errors.

Comment: What you are doing by all those steps is creating a new IISExpress config file for your app. You could achieve the same results by doing `appcmd.exe list site /xml | appcmd delete site /in` to delete all site configurations present on your IISExpress instance. Be carefull if you want to preserve any of them and remove them one by one. Close VS and reopen it, the next time you launch the project it will recreate the site config for you.